# Android 5.0 List Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a list of items that is composed of a `View` and a `TextView`. I defined an animation:

```
View mView = findViewById(R.id.view);
Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
String transitionName = getString(R.string.my_transition);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                mView, transitionName);
startActivity(detailIntent, options.toBundle());
```

and in my list_item.xml I have:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_dimen"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="@color/accent"
    android:transitionName="@string/my_transition"/>
```

The transition works fine for the first item, but no matter which item in the list I click, the animation always comes from the first item, and if I scroll to the point where the first item is out of view the app force closes when I click on an item. How do I attach to animation to a specific list item?

**SOLUTION**:

Per MarcaoAS answer, I had to attach the view to the specific root view. I am implementing a `Master-Detail` relationship so I have a `Fragment` for my list which contains a `Callbacks` :

```
public interface Callbacks {
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}
```

I had to edit this to take a `View` as a parameter instead of a `String`: `onItemSelected(View view)`.

Likewise, I had to make this change where ever that is referenced. When the `Fragment` was generated (I selected Master-Detail when creating the project in `Android Studio`) the `onListItemClick` was overridden:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(view);
}
```

As you can see I once again replaced the `id` with the `view` that is passed in.

In my `ListActivity` where I have my original code posted above I now have:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(View view) {
    //tablet
    if (mTwoPane) {
        //tablet handling 
    }
    //phone
    else {
        View mView = view.findViewById(R.id.view);
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        String transitionName = getString(R.string.my_transition);
        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                mView, transitionName);
        startActivity(detailIntent, options.toBundle());
    }
}
```

Once again passing in the `View` from the `Fragment` class. This solved my issue.

Comment: To be able to properly answer, please provide an information on **what** **is** 'this' and the code around, because we don't see enough context to be able to answer what's wrong in your code.
I would suggest you're calling this from Activity code in which case the 'findViewById' always finds first view in your list and not the one you've clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your the code below is returning the item view.

```
View mView = findViewById(R.id.view);
```

If you are calling this from an activity it will always return the first item because your items may have the same id. Try to do that in your onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    View mView = v.findViewById(R.id.view);
    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    String transitionName = getString(R.string.my_transition);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, mView, transitionName);
    startActivity(detailIntent, options.toBundle());
}
```

Comment: This was basically the solution, I made in edit in my post showing exactly what I had to do. Thank you for the answer!